# How to configure apache to accept POST cross domain

Tags: apache, cross-domain

I need to configure apache on ubuntu to accpect POST cross-domain.

I tried like that http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html:

1. Install mod_header
2. Add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
   header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

but that doesn't work.

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, cache-control, origin, x-requested-with, x-file-name, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:xxx.amazonaws.com
Origin:local.com
Referer:local.com/test/test.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:27
Content-Type:text/html Date:Fri, 10 May 2013 10:30:10 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Vary:Accept-Encoding X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
```

Anyone can help me ? Thank you so much

Comment: Can you show the request/response you are sending/receiving from the server? A good article I used to allow CORS was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, cache-control, origin, x-requested-with, x-file-name, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:xxx.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://local.com
Referer:http://local.com/test/test.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31

Comment: Response header:Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:27
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 10 May 2013 10:30:10 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6

Comment: Sorry I have to divide to 2 comments. I dont understand that does not return the string I write in file recieve

Comment: You could have edited your original question ...

Comment: Posting more of your code might be helpful - the request appears to be returning a 200 status code, which means it was successful.

Comment: But that does not return anything.
I print a string "hello" but nothing display in reponse. I see in the Status of Developer Tool of Google Chrome, status: Load cancelled

Comment: If I try post to http://www.torrentplease.com/dropzone.php with the same parameters, that always works :(

Comment: It seems unlikely, but I have seen examples using the htaccess stating that you should place the asterisk within speech marks, i.e Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

Comment: One other thing (again, seems unlikely, I don't think POST requests are cached) is that the request may be cached. Try appending a random number on to the end of the request.

Comment: The only other difference I can see between those two sites is the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header. Try adding this header to the response: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER, X-File-Name, Cache-Control

Comment: I tried add ?Math.random() at the end of link but the result is same :(

Comment: See the answer I've updated - this appears to of worked for others.

Comment: Thank you, that works when I add header

Comment: Great - if you could accept the answer so that others can see this as solved, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

Going on an answer provided to someone in a thread on the jQuery forums, you may need to provide the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header, in order to permit certain headers to be sent.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, X-File-Name")
```

Reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-5-latest-chrome-post-ajax-request-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-url-request-header-field-x-requested-with-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers